# General questions about node bcrypt stuff

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

This function processes a username and password supplied by the user. What object stores this information in node for the program to access? What loads the code to provides the values for this object?

```
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var mc = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var playersCollection;

var start = function(req, res){
    var playername = req.body.playername;
    var password = req.body.password;

    playersCollection.findOne({playername: playername}, function(err, player){

    if (err || !player){
        req.session.destroy(function(err) {
        res.redirect("/?error=invalid playername or password"); 
        });
        return;
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, player.password, function(err, authenticated){
        if(authenticated){
            req.session.player = player;
            delete req.session.player._id;
            res.redirect("/" + player.room);
        } else {
            req.session.destroy(function(err) {
            res.redirect("/?error=invalid playername or password");
            });
        }
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is accessing MongoDB for credentials

Answer (score 0):

We're doing this in [Drywall](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall). [Here are the two main methods we use](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall/blob/master/schema/User.js#L45-L62).

```
...
userSchema.statics.encryptPassword = function(password, done) {
  var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      done(err, hash);
    });
  });
};
userSchema.statics.validatePassword = function(password, hash, done) {
  var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
    done(err, res);
  });
};
...
```

Hopefully using our code as a reference helps you.